# Error after updating to latest core version

Tags: 8, updating

After Drupalcon last week I felt comfortable using composer, and I was ready to update our site from 8.4.6 to 8.5.1. I have done just that (luckily in a dev environment) and now the front page of the site loads fine (as well as the user/login page), but any other page I try to navigate too just throws up an error

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>
> InvalidArgumentException: Field is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 580 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->get() (Line: 49)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EditorialContentEntityBase->isPublished() (Line: 188)
>   content_moderation_entity_access(Object, "view", Object)
>   call_user_func_array("content_moderation_entity_access", Array) (Line: 402)
>   Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll("entity_access", Array) (Line: 96)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessControlHandler->;access(Object, "view", Object, 1) (Line: 702)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->access("view", Object, 1) (Line: 177)
>   Drupal\block_content\Plugin\Block\BlockContentBlock->blockAccess(Object) (Line: 118)
>   Drupal\block\BlockAccessControlHandler->checkAccess(Object, "view", Object) (Line: 105)
>   Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase->access(Object, 1) (Line: 119)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessControlHandler->access(Object, "view", Object, 1) (Line: 362)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->access("view", NULL, 1) (Line: 56)
>   Drupal\block\Plugin\DisplayVariant\BlockPageVariant->build() (Line: 259)
>   Drupal\block\BlockRepository->getVisibleBlocksPerRegion(Array) (Line: 137)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, "kernel.view", Object)
>   call user_func(Array, Object, "kernel.view", Object) (Line: 111)
>   Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch("kernel.view", Object) (Line: 156)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 184)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 121)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 75)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
>   Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 664)
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Now I have no idea what that means, anyone out there experienced anything like this before?

Comment: Did you run /update.php ?

Comment: Or use `drush updb`

Comment: Yes, that definitely means you either didn't run updates or the updates didn't complete successfully. there are some known issues around the block_content_8400() update, partially fixed in the latest dev version